# What are my options to encrypt a file before writing it on Python?

Tags: open-source, library, python, security, encryption

I need something simple, where I can:

1. encrypt it with a password (salt, everything related)
2. write it to disk

Then the opposite:

1. read from disk
2. decrypt it with my password

Everything I find out there is either not maintained properly, or doesn't have examples, or outdated, or needs 50 lines of code to be used which I have to maintain myself.

I would like to have something as simple as what I do locally on my terminal. I do this on my terminal:

To encrypt:

```
$ cat data | openssl des3 -salt | dd of=output.des3
```

To decrypt:

```
$ dd if=output.des3 | openssl des3 -d -salt
```

How can I do this in Python in a cross plaform and secure way?

Comment: I found this https://www.pythoncentral.io/hashing-strings-with-python/ and this https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html Hope that helps.

Comment: @onurcano22 Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I don't want to hash. Hashing doesn't preserve data and is a one-way function. I need to encrypt data against a password.

Comment: I haven't dealed with encryption / decryption much and I guess many others didn't do either. I believe you'll get better help at https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @onurcano22 I was afraid it would be called software recommendation... but I just posted a question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

First off, avoid 3DES encryption.  It exists only as a stop-gap created because of the panic after regular DES was broken but before people had any reasonable alternative.  It's only marginally more secure than plain DES (which is trivially broken) and is horribly inefficient compared to more modern stuff (even Blowfish, which is not much more recent, is faster *and* more secure).

Now, as far as doing what you're talking about in Python, I would suggest taking a look at [Cryptography](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography/2.2.2).  It's *the* de-facto standard for cryptographic operations in Python that aren't explicitly handled by some special purpose module (like the SSL support in the standard library).  While I've never done anything directly with it myself, it's used by a wide variety of other projects to get crypto-support.